# Error in confusion matrix from Naive Bayes model

Tags: r, machine-learning

Any idea why the confusion matrix isn't working for this run? I'm just running a straight-forward text classification model of texts and whether they are spam or ham. I know it's a mismatch of factor vs. non-factor, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EELtGlXMLwq6hkzQBKkKvDY5kHrFg58A/view?usp=sharing

```
#First, download the data
#https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("SnowballC")
install.packages("wordcloud")
install.packages("RColorBrewer")
install.packages("e1071")
install.packages("caret")

library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer) 
library(e1071)
library(caret) 

sms_raw <- read.csv("G:/My Drive/Big Data Analytics Class/SMSSpamCollection.csv")
View(sms_raw)
sms_raw$class <- sms_raw$ï..class1
sms_raw <- sms_raw[,2:3]
colnames(sms_raw) <- c("Msg","Tag")
table(sms_raw$Tag)
prop.table(table(sms_raw$Tag))
#Visualize things
spam <- subset(sms_raw,Tag=="spam")
wordcloud(spam$Msg,max.words=40,colors=brewer.pal(7,"Paired"),random.order=FALSE)
ham <- subset(sms_raw,Tag=="ham")
wordcloud(ham$Msg,max.words=40,colors=brewer.pal(7,"Paired"),random.order=FALSE)
#Document term matrix
sms_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(sms_raw$Msg))
sms_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus,control=
                                 list(tolower = TRUE,
                                      removeNumbers=TRUE,
                                      stopwords=TRUE,
                                      removePunctuation=TRUE,
                                      stemming=TRUE))
dim(sms_dtm)
#The document term matrix has each row as the message and each column as a word

#Training and testing datasets
sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[1:4457,]
sms_dtm_test <- sms_dtm[4458:5572,]

sms_train_labels <- sms_raw[1:4457, ]$Tag
sms_test_labels <- sms_raw[4458:5572, ]$Tag

prop.table(table(sms_train_labels))
prop.table(table(sms_test_labels))

threshold <- 0.1
min_freq = round(sms_dtm$nrow*(threshold/100),0)
min_freq

freq_words <- findFreqTerms(x=sms_dtm, lowfreq = min_freq)
str(freq_words)

sms_dtm_freq_train <- sms_dtm_train[ , freq_words]
sms_dtm_freq_test <- sms_dtm_test[ , freq_words]
dim(sms_dtm_freq_train)
dim(sms_dtm_freq_test)

#Create categorical data for Naive Bayes
convert_values <- function(x) {
  x <- ifelse(x > 0, "Yes", "No")
}

sms_train <- apply(sms_dtm_freq_train,MARGIN=2,convert_values)
sms_test <- apply(sms_dtm_freq_test,MARGIN=2,convert_values)

#Naive Bayes
sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(sms_train, sms_train_labels)
sms_test_pred <- predict(sms_classifier,sms_test)

str(sms_classifier)
str(sms_test_pred)

confusionMatrix(data=sms_test_pred,reference=sms_test_labels,
                positive="spam",dnn = c("Prediction","Actual"))
```

Comment: If it's a mismatch of factor vs non-factor, can you just add stringsAsFactors = F to your first csv import?